# How can I stop Mac Mail continually caching attachments?

Tags: mail.app, email, attachments, yahoo

Two problems really:

1. I'm using Mac Mail version 5.3 on Mac OSX. My Yahoo mailbox is continually fetching new mail i.e. the wheel by 'yahoo is continually spinning. It has been doing this for a few days. I have already tried quitting and reopening Mac mail a few times.
2. I can see see from Window>Activity that Yahoo inbox is caching attachments. Even if I stop it, it starts again within seconds.

Answer (score 2):

In Preferences, within Mail, in the **Accounts** tab, for each of your accounts there is an **Advanced** tab.  There is an option called **Keep copies for offline viewing** which is a drop-down box. By Choosing **All messages, but omit attachments**, you can set it to never cache the attachments.